# How do you remove comments from a specific item of a Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

The delete () function of the IComments interface (PnP) does not delete the comment I select through the index, how can I use it? (@pnp/sp/comments)

[in this way I get the comments of the item to which I will pass the index, but once I try to use the delete it is not read.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEBMr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the clear method exposed by IComments. The clear method would delete all comments on the item returned.

```js
  const item = sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Title').items.getById(1);
  await item.comments.clear();
```

Or you could use the snippet below which will delete the comment with the specified id.

```js
  const commentId = 2000;
  await item.comments.getById(commentId).delete();
```